# Vba - webscraping using ng-click

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, web-scraping, automation

I am using Selenium and I would like to be able to click on the following

```html
<a ng-click="download()">download</a>'
```

This is an 'a' tag.
I am not sure how the code would be like to click onto an 'a' tag that has got ng-click in it.

```
  Dim d As WebDriver
  Set d = New ChromeDriver
Const URL = "url of the website - not public"
With d
    .Start "Chrome"
    .get URL
    .Window.Maximize
    .FindElementById("Search").SendKeys "information to search"
    .Wait 1000
    .FindElementById("Submit").Click
    .Wait 1000
    'then I need to click the following <a ng-click="download()">download</a>
End With
```

Only step I am missing is to be able to click on that last bit. Thank you for the help in advance :)

Comment: Did this get solved?

Comment: Intranet Website? Click on Submit suggest a form. If it is a form, check request sended after clicking submit and rebuild that request witj differnt seach phrase. That would be far cleaner and easier thaz bothering with javasxript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired element is an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *elementToBeClickable* and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `FindElementByCss`:

  ```
  d.FindElementByCss("a[ng-click^='download']").click
  ```
- Using `FindElementByXPath`:

  ```
  d.FindElementByXPath("//a[starts-with(@ng-click, 'download') and text()='download']").click
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `xpath` :

```
.FindElementByXPath("//*[@ng-click='download()']").Click
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what [attribute = value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) css selectors are for. You can target the `ng-click` attribute by its value:

```
d.FindElementByCss("[ng-click='download()']").click
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier (and more efficient) to see more relevant HTML code, but you can loop through the `a` tags and find the one that has the text: `download`. Once found, you can try to click on it then exit the loop.

```
Dim a As Selenium.WebElement
For Each a In d.FindElementsByTag("a")
    If a.Text = "download" Then
        a.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thank you , I will give it a try :)